# Alignment of the footnote line

Tags: footnotes, right-to-left, persian

How I can force latex to align the footnote line in some pages to left, right or even center?

As you see in this picture below, I want to push the footnote separator line to left side of this paper, but how?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: normally the line is where you show, presumably the page layout is assuming rtl and so it has flipped but it depends on the details of how things are specified, please add a small complete document that makes the page image that you show.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, XePersian has an autofootnoterule that places the footnote line above the first footnote, i.e. if the first footnote is in Persian, the line is right, and to the left for English.

Comment: @Gahir this feature is on by default, so if you have an updated texlive distribution, it should work. Make sure you run xelatex at least twice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any (right) coding way to change the position of that line in a document?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code in Persian texts for Latin footnotes:
`\LTRfootnote{cone}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please elaborate on your solution. E.g. the required packages and the output of the command.

Comment: @user137777 No this is not my answer, I gave you (-1) because my question was clear, I need to change the style, type, color etc. or changing the position of that line arbitrary.